# While-End Loop not working properly Python GUI

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to make program that will popup a another window if the correct password is entered within 3 attemps. When the wrong password is entered for the 3rd third it will print 'bye', but this program seems to print 'bye' on the first time an incorrect password is entered.

```
import Tkinter

def win1():
    # this is the main/root window
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Stock Plus system")
    root.geometry('400x150')
    b2Var=Tkinter.StringVar()
    s=0


    def textboxvalue():
     s=3
     while (s==0):
         global s 
         textvalue=b2Var.get()
         if textvalue ==('stock123'):
            label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Welcome to stock plus system, press login again to start using')
            label4.grid(row=3,column=1)
            Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=win2)
            Button_1.grid(row=2,column=1)

         else:
            s=s-1
            label3=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Try again')
            label3.grid(row=3,column=1)
     else:
         label5=Tkinter.Label(root,text='bitch')
         label5.grid(row=4,column=1)


    Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=textboxvalue)
    Button_1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    b1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    b2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

    box1Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Username:')
    box1Label.grid(row=0)
    box2Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Password:')
    box2Label.grid(row=1)
    box1Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b1Var,width=12)
    box1Text.grid(row=0, column=1)
    box2Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b2Var,width=12)
    box2Text.grid(row=1, column=1)



    root.mainloop()
def win2():


    # this is the child window

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Window 2")
    s1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

    square1Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s1Var)
    square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)
    square2Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
    square2Label.grid(row=0, column=6)
win1()
if (s==3):
    label5=Tkinter.Label(root,text=' start using')
    label5.grid(row=4,column=1)
```

Comment: You'll need to rectify the indentation in your code.

Comment: Wheich one actually?

Comment: There are lots of indentation errors, every function is not indented correctly. It sometimes happens when you paste it into the textbox. Can you run what you have now? I can see many issues.

Comment: i can run actually, just give me a solution for the while-loop thing please

Comment: If I copy-and-paste this into a file on my computer and try to run it, I get an error on line 3: "IndentationError: expected an indented block". This is because the code inside `win1()` is not indented properly in what you have pasted here. If you want somebody to help you'll need to fix your post.

Comment: @Teeban Edit your post. Delete all the code. Copy the code you have, paste it here. Then mark the code, and press ctr+k.

Comment: User5061 just done what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the while loop always runs 3 times on each press of the login button, since the input is the same on each iteration it drops into the `if (s==3):` if statement and prints 'bye' every time.

Your function `textboxvalue` is called once per button click, not once and then the loop is executed on each subsequent click. I think you have misunderstood this somewhat.

What you need is some persistence between calls to `textboxvalue`, we'll use a global variable. You should remember to set this back to 0 if any more login attempts are required later.

Now you need an `if` rather than a while, as it should only run once each call to `textboxvalue`.

The below code demonstrates how to fix it.

```
tries = 0

def textboxvalue():
    global tries

    if (tries < 3):
       textvalue=b2Var.get()
       if textvalue ==('stock123'):
           label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Welcome to stock plus system, press login again to start using')
           label4.grid(row=3,column=1)
           Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=win2)
           Button_1.grid(row=2,column=1)

       else:
           tries += 1
           label3=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Try again')
           label3.grid(row=3,column=1)

    if (tries==3):
        label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='bye')
        label4.grid(row=4,column=1)
```

As you are having issues integrating the above example with the rest of your code. Here's a complete version.

```
import Tkinter

def win1():
    global root
    global tries
    # this is the main/root window
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Stock Plus system")
    root.geometry('400x150')
    b2Var=Tkinter.StringVar()
    tries = 0

def win2():
    # this is the child window

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Window 2")
    s1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

    square1Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s1Var)
    square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)
    square2Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
    square2Label.grid(row=0, column=6)

def textboxvalue():
    global tries

    if (tries < 3):
       textvalue=b2Var.get()
       if textvalue ==('stock123'):
           label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Welcome to stock plus system, press login again to start using')
           label4.grid(row=3,column=1)
           Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=win2)
           Button_1.grid(row=2,column=1)

       else:
           tries += 1
           label3=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Try again')
           label3.grid(row=3,column=1)

    if (tries==3):
        label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='bye')
        label4.grid(row=4,column=1)

win1()
Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=textboxvalue)
Button_1.grid(row=2, column=1)
b1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
b2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

box1Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Username:')
box1Label.grid(row=0)
box2Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Password:')
box2Label.grid(row=1)
box1Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b1Var,width=12)
box1Text.grid(row=0, column=1)
box2Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b2Var,width=12)
box2Text.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()


if (tries==3):
    label5=Tkinter.Label(root,text=' start using')
    label5.grid(row=4,column=1)
```

Comment: Paul thanks for the answer but it says ' if (tries < 3):
NameError: global name 'tries' is not defined '

Comment: Did you include the global definition of `tries` in your code? It's the very first line of my code example.

Comment: Did you replace your `textboxvalue` function with my entire example? That's strange as its the exact error I get if I comment out `tries = 0`.

Comment: Yes i did, i tried adding tries=0 before global tries. The program opened but it did not display bye when tries =3

Comment: I added my complete code, try to see if thats better.

Comment: if  i had a chance to meet you i would have bought the the biggest set in the Burger King

Comment: No probs the accepted answer and maybe an upvote will be enough.